# C# Parse nested JSON Array to get values

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I've been searching and trying to get this to work for hours and i'm completely  out of ideas. I have JSON text that i'm trying to read and can't see it get it to work. Here is the JSON text.

> [   {
>       "first_aired": "2018-03-03T01:00:00.000Z",
>       "episode": {
>         "season": 3,
>         "number": 13,
>         "title": "Warning Shot",
>         "ids": {
>           "trakt": 2814272,
>           "tvdb": 6445735,
>           "imdb": "tt7462514",
>           "tmdb": 1429184,
>           "tvrage": 0
>         }
>       },
>       "show": {
>         "title": "Blindspot",
>         "year": 2015,
>         "ids": {
>           "trakt": 98980,
>           "slug": "blindspot",
>           "tvdb": 295647,
>           "imdb": "tt4474344",
>           "tmdb": 62710,
>           "tvrage": 44628
>         }
>       }   },   {
>       "first_aired": "2018-03-03T01:00:00.000Z",
>       "episode": {
>         "season": 2,
>         "number": 16,
>         "title": "Hammock + Balcony",
>         "ids": {
>           "trakt": 2874663,
>           "tvdb": 6535389,
>           "imdb": "tt7820776",
>           "tmdb": 1428050,
>           "tvrage": 0
>         }
>       },
>       "show": {
>         "title": "MacGyver",
>         "year": 2016,
>         "ids": {
>           "trakt": 107792,
>           "slug": "macgyver-2016",
>           "tvdb": 311902,
>           "imdb": "tt1399045",
>           "tmdb": 67133,
>           "tvrage": {}
>         }
>       }   } ]

I'm trying to get the "episode -> season" and "episode - > number"
This is the code ive been working with and also a fiddle below.

```
    string json = "[{\"first_aired\":\"2018-03-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"episode\":{\"season\":3,\"number\":13,\"title\":\"Warning Shot\",\"ids\":{\"trakt\":2814272,\"tvdb\":6445735,\"imdb\":\"tt7462514\",\"tmdb\":1429184,\"tvrage\":0}},\"show\":{\"title\":\"Blindspot\",\"year\":2015,\"ids\":{\"trakt\":98980,\"slug\":\"blindspot\",\"tvdb\":295647,\"imdb\":\"tt4474344\",\"tmdb\":62710,\"tvrage\":44628}}},{\"first_aired\":\"2018-03-03T01:00:00.000Z\",\"episode\":{\"season\":2,\"number\":16,\"title\":\"Hammock + Balcony\",\"ids\":{\"trakt\":2874663,\"tvdb\":6535389,\"imdb\":\"tt7820776\",\"tmdb\":1428050,\"tvrage\":0}},\"show\":{\"title\":\"MacGyver\",\"year\":2016,\"ids\":{\"trakt\":107792,\"slug\":\"macgyver-2016\",\"tvdb\":311902,\"imdb\":\"tt1399045\",\"tmdb\":67133,\"tvrage\":null}}}]";
    JArray obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);


    foreach (var result in obj)
    {
        foreach (JObject tvshow in result["episode"])
        {
            string season_num = (string)tvshow["season"];
            string episode_num = (string)tvshow["number"];

            Console.WriteLine(season_num + " - " + episode_num );
        }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/speUyL

Thank's for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Also, the JSON shows that the season and number are numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have nested objects, so you will need to first extract the `episode` object and then from the `episode` you can access it's properties which are `number` and `season` etc:

```
foreach (var result in obj)
{
    var episode = result["episode"];
    Console.WriteLine(episode["season"]);
    Console.WriteLine(episode["number"]);
}
```

This prints the result you are trying to do. Following is the updated fiddle demo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WN545C

A easy approach is to have DTO c# classes for your json and then Deserialize the json result in to `List<T>`. The classes for your json would be :

```
public class Ids
{
    public int trakt { get; set; }
    public int tvdb { get; set; }
    public string imdb { get; set; }
    public int tmdb { get; set; }
    public int tvrage { get; set; }
}

public class Episode
{
    public int season { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Ids ids { get; set; }
}

public class Ids2
{
    public int trakt { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public int tvdb { get; set; }
    public string imdb { get; set; }
    public int tmdb { get; set; }
    public object tvrage { get; set; }
}

public class Show
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public Ids2 ids { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public DateTime first_aired { get; set; }
    public Episode episode { get; set; }
    public Show show { get; set; }
}
```

An easy way to get the classes generated is by using [Json2CSharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/#) or either using the Visual Studio feature which can [paste JSON as C# classes using Paste Special](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/).
and now you can deserialize and access each season data more better way:

```
var seasons = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Season>>(json);

foreach (var season in seasons)
{

    Console.WriteLine(season.episode.title);
    Console.WriteLine(season.first_aired);
    Console.WriteLine(season.episode.season);
    Console.WriteLine(season.episode.number);
}
```

You can play with the demo for that here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hukLQI

Comment: AH okay got it! Thank you so much for your help i really really appreciate it so much! Have a great day :)

Comment: @ViNSaNiTY i have added more details with a more better way instead of playing with `JArray` and `JObject` thing

Comment: Wow you didn't have to do all that. Thank you i understand what you did and am going to learn a lot from this.